# Put the least significant byte of one variable to another

Tags: c

I have a little piece of code that puts the least significant byte of one variable to another :

```
int main(){
    int x = 0x89ABCDEF;
    int y = 0x76543210;

    printf("Before operations x : %x; y : %x\n", x, y);

    //easy solution works only with integers
    int result = (x & 0x000000FF) | (y & 0xFFFFFF00);
    printf("result : %x\n", result);
}
```

However I don't like the way I manipulate the bytes, it is very type dependant.

Is it possible to get the result by using methods such as sizeof(variable) and shifts ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: well what other types do you want to support? Obviously this only makes sense for integers, and on modern machines there aren't many choices in terms of size (1 2, 4, 8 bytes, and maybe 16 on some compilers as an extension).

Comment: If you want to machine independent, you need `sizeof`, `CHAR_BIT` and have to use unsigned types only. Or you use unsigned `stdint.h` types. Note that a bytes is not defined to be 8 bits wide.

Answer (score 3):

```
int mask = 0xFF;
int result = (x & mask) | (y & (~mask));
```

Is above helpful?

Answer (score -1):

Why not use:

```
int result = (x & 0xFFULL) | (y & ~0xFFULL);
```

unsigned long long should be the biggest integer type on your platform, and the calculation will work for any smaller integer type. Doing it with non-integer types would be intrinsically type- and platform-dependent, and is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Apart from being inefficient, your compiler should warn about a truncation cast if `int` has less than 64 bits. Also you are mixing unsigned and signed types in an implementation defined way. That is exactly what OP seems to want to avoid.

Comment: Pretty much any compiler would optimise away the extra bits. I'm not casting anything, and gcc at least is perfectly happy with that code. The op said he wanted to swap the least significant byte with more types than just int, I'm not sure what other behaviour than the one I've suggested he could hope to achieve with sizeof().

Comment: I menat you **have to** cast to avoid the truncation warning. You should enable warnings (`-Wconversion`). Always enable warnings - the compiler is your friend! OP can use a C11 `_Generic` macro, a macro as such or single functions per type. (Whereas, the question does not  ask for other types) Either way, you made the same mistake, as you use a signed type and rely on `CHAR_BIT == 8`.

Comment: Fair enough, though -Wall -ansi -std=c99 -pedantic doesn't complain. I interpreted the op's question as wanting to take the lowest 8 bits and put them into another variable, and his issue was that using '0xFFFFFF00' made assumptions about sizeof(int). I agree that it's a bit more complicated it you care about the least significant _byte_ and portability to platforms with non eight bit bytes (though I'd question how much bit twiddling code is usefully portable in such cases).

Comment: `-Wall` is not a sufficient setting (I really wish they would make much more warnings default (standard and gcc), thus enforce actively disabling instead of enabling warnings) and `-Wpedantic` (`-pedantic` is a legacy) is primarily according to the standard.

Comment: Point is, OP did explicitly stated "byte", which is a defined term in the standard. And, yes, you can: `mask = (((1U<<(CHAR_BIT-1))-1)<<1)+1` and `unsigned` instead of `int`.